# sync git with salesforce, including deletions?

Tags: salesforcedx, git, cicd

I'm starting with a new project and I'd like to start fresh. Unfortunately, for various reasons, my Salesforce instance is already cluttered up with a lot of metadata

I would like Git to be my source of truth. I don't want there to be anything in Salesforce that isn't in Git. So I'd like to deploy an empty repository so that all that metadata will be deleted.

In the future obviously I'll also want to delete metadata from SF through deleting it from git. Right now when I delete something in the repo, it mysteriously doesn't get deleted in SF.

I want this to be the default behavior. How can I make it happen?

Comment: You could switch to using scratch orgs which are necessarily created, clean, regularly (since they can only live for up to 30 days). As to handling deletions, you may be able to enable metadata "source tracking" on your org. This would detect "deletions" (it can't differentiate between a rename and a deletion+add) and delete the now missing metadata (if valid to do so). See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm) for more.

Comment: Scratch orgs are part of the solution, but what if I want to delete something from production through git?

Comment: @PhilW I guess source tracking is supported only for Dev & DevPro sbx? Also, I believe source tracking would be helpful only to find the difference between org and local workspace to always keep the code up-to-date. While one would keep the local working directly and git repo also in sync via vscode, I guess the OP is asking more about how to achieve deletions via git changes and org (without having to do deployments via vscode)?

Comment: Deletions are done via [destructive deployments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm). Git is only a source version control which is to be used as single source of truth. AFAIK, there is no OOB or standard feature to continuous deploy deletions from GIT to sandbox or prod orgs. I've not yet explored any custom solutions available in open source or any capability available in paid tools like Flosum, GearSet etc.

Comment: @arut I agree that deletion from production requires a destructive deployment. Enabling source tracking allows automated deletions against sandboxes simply by the file no longer existing in the workspace (directory tree). Obviously you need to have had the metadata files you don't want in your workspace when syncing source tracking, but subsequent deletion locally will cause `force:source:push` to delete those metadata items on the org.

Comment: For use with production I expect it would be necessary to write some scripting that detected metadata file deletions across the relevant git commits/merges and generated the destructive changes XML file.

Comment: @arut don't confuse VSCode and sfdx CLI. You don't need the former to use the latter. We have written scripts using the CLI to automate various things (such as CI) without the need to use tools like Gearset or Copado etc.

Comment: @PhilW My poor choice of words; I meant to write about SFDX CLI, but ended up writing VS Code. However, the main points that I was trying to bring out are: (a) Is source tracking supported beyond Dev & DevPro sbx? (Most may have full/partial copy for UAT env). (b) Source tracking is great feature for developers to collaborate and write their code without overwriting each other's code (which was a common pitfall in org based dev).

Comment: c) OP should be clear that Version control and Deployment tools (like SFDX CLI, ANT) should be treated as independent but interacting pieces for DevOps, so their purposes differ. Like you had also pointed out, there would be some scripting required to achieve this.